# Is it ok to use Webview on Android to browse Youtube channel?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, youtube

Currently, I'm using WebView to show my youtube channel videos on my android app. My question is - is it ok to use WebView instead of some youtube API and widgets? 
What kind of problems and possible vulnerabilities can I face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `webview` and user plays video from your channel, user will have access to videos outside your channel and user can get lost watching other videos. Using `Youtube api` you can show only content from your channel nothing else.

use of `webview` or `youtube api` . depends on your preference and time of development. if you have time go with `youtube api`.

**note : `youtube api` has daily quota limits**

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` in Android OS is basically an instance of Google Chrome. It will update each time Google Chrome updates - so it will have all the relevant changes and fixes. You can easily use it to show your youtube chaneel. You will not have the whole control and possibilities API gives you - for example users will see all the videos, not just yours - this is a downside. If you don't need this control - you're good to go with a `WebView` implementation.

Hope it helps.